# Remap shortcuts my combinin pyautogui and pynput

Tags: python, hotkeys, pyautogui, pynput

I am trying to remap a shortcut combining pynput and pyautogui, but I am getting the error

in execute
    with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
AttributeError: module 'pynput.keyboard' has no attribute 'pressed'

```
from pynput import keyboard
import pyautogui

# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='z')},
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='x')}
]

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def execute():
    pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!\n', interval=secs_between_keys)
    #pyautogui.hotkey('cmd', 'v')

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I am a total beginner and cannot figure out why I am not able to use pyautogui functions here. Would you kindly enlighten me? many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete and tested example using pynput:

```
from pynput import keyboard

# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl_l, keyboard.KeyCode(char='z')},
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl_r, keyboard.KeyCode(char='z')},    
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl_l, keyboard.KeyCode(char='x')},    
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl_r, keyboard.KeyCode(char='x')}
]

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def execute():
    print("Here I am")

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The main problem seems to me related to use specific key combinations (e.g. Control + C) that are used by OS or other applications.

Comment: this code, unfortunately, is also broken... File "/Users/martinhorst/Documents/teste.py", line 14, in execute
    pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!\n', interval=secs_between_keys)
NameError: name 'secs_between_keys' is not defined

Comment: Sorry @MartinHorst but I do not have pyautogui on this pc, try now I simplified it. Adding your pyautogui part should be trivial, let me know if you want me to help with that.

Comment: thanks for that - so far so good, I had already managed to make the shell print the messages; the problem I was facing was how to make ctrl-z or ctrl-x to trigger another key combination(s) :)

Comment: So what you want to do is, for example, pressing control + c and triggering a control + a and control + b?

Comment: exactly - I would like to assign to a hotkey a sequence of other hotkeys (with some waiting times between them), something like AutoHotKey does on PCs (as there is not AutoHotKey for Mac)

Comment: Mmmh I think I understand better.

In this case I would leave the listener heavy-lifting to the Mac (https://lifehacker.com/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-any-menu-action-in-any-p-343328) and then bind my new hotkey to a python script that is just running the pyautogui keypresses / pauses

Comment: well, gonna have a try! so, how would you assign a shortcut to a python script?

Comment: Check Automator or https://lifehacker.com/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-any-menu-action-in-any-p-343328

Answer (score 1):

You want `press` which takes the `key` argument, instead of `pressed`.

From the docs:-

```
Controller.press(key)
Presses a key.

A key may be either a string of length 1, one of the Key members or a KeyCode.
```